# pod install 'Firebase/Auth' results in [Bug] Bus Error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I faced this issue with Ruby, they suggested this was either a problem with ethon or apple silicon.  Wondered if anyone else has run into this and could point me the right way to solve.  Please look below:

**Steps:**

Installed Cocoapods to use Google Firebase on new Mac mini. Successful install
Went through proper steps to generate a pod file in my Xcode project folder
Attempted to "pod install", and ran into the issue cited below

Please see details below in the following sections (bolded): *Environment*, *Pod File*, *Mac Terminal Output*, *Crash Report* - Full terminal output and crash report omitted here due to text length limitation on this site.

**Environment:**

- OS: macOS Big Sur 11.3.1 (20E241)
- IDE: Xcode 12.5 (12E262)
- CocoaPods:
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods.rb
- Ruby: ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580)
  [universal.arm64e-darwin20]

**Pod File**

```
#Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project platform :ios, '9.0' target 'Mark' do
# Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks 

use_frameworks!
    
    # Pods for Mark
 
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    
end
```

**Mac Terminal Output:**

Analyzing dependencies
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.1/lib/ffi/library.rb:275: [BUG] Bus Error at 0x00000001007c4000
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.arm64e-darwin20]
...

Comment: I am not an expert but I think that's a pretty old version of Ruby 2.6.0. Isn't 2.7.3 The stable release that works on M1?

Comment: Thanks Jay.  Makes sense.  I'm new to Mac world so didn't want to monkey with it too much at first.  To get the project going without disrupting my environment I ended up downloading the SDK and doing it the old fashioned way.  Took a little time, but I figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

> Running gem install --user-install ffi -- --enable-libffi-alloc fixed my issue (Mac pro -M1 Pro)

The more details: https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/864#issuecomment-1024260535